If there are no rows, return all rows
SELECT u.id FROM user u WHERE u.id IN (7, 11)
if I have no results for the ids specified, I want to return all users, similar to this query :
SELECT u.id FROM user u
the difficulty and I want to keep the logical operator IN
to schematize my needs :
SELECT u.id FROM user u WHERE IF u.id IN (7, 11) = null THEN IN(*) ELSE IF u.id IN (7, 11) <> null THEN u.id IN (7, 11)
if possible avoid offering me a subquery, in the IN(*) part

While you can achieve what you're looking for using conditional queries, it's almost always better to implement that business logic at the application layer and not within the database itself. For example, if you return all rows when you have no matches on your WHERE clause, then your application would not know that there were no initial matches. IMHO it makes more sense to make a query from the application and make a new query if the first query didn't have any matches.

This seems like a strange requirement to begin with. What is the use case?

In SQL Server you can actually use TOP (1) WITH TIES to do this very efficiently.
SELECT TOP (1) WITH TIES
  *
FROM (
    SELECT u.id, 1 AS Ordering
    FROM user u
    WHERE u.id IN (7, 11)

    UNION ALL

    SELECT u.id, 2
    FROM user u
) u
ORDER BY
  Ordering;

But for MySQL you will need something like this
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT u.id
    FROM user u
    WHERE u.id IN (7, 11)
)
SELECT *
FROM cte

UNION ALL

SELECT *
FROM user u
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM cte);

Another option is to use window functions
SELECT u.id
FROM (
    SELECT
      u.id,
      SUM(u.id IN (7, 11)) OVER () AS countMatches
    FROM user u
) u
WHERE countMatches = 0 OR u.id IN (7, 11);


What does "cte" stand for?

It's just an alias for the subquery, you can put anything there, such as RelevantUsers and then use it again later on.

SELECT u.id
FROM user u
WHERE u.id IN (7, 11)
   OR NOT EXISTS ( 
     SELECT u.id 
     FROM user u
     WHERE u.id IN (7, 11)
     );

https://dbfiddle.uk/_yzWanfN
